# Binary file from C# to Python

Tags: c#, python

How does open a binary file created by C# app in Python? I know structure file in C#.

I tried to find information on the internet, but I could not.

Structure:

```
[Serializable]
public class FileClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<Class1> OC1 { get; set; }
    public Class2 C2 { get; set; }
    public Class3 C3 { get; set; }

    public FileClass()
    {
        OC1 = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();
        C2 = new Class2();
        C3 = new Class3();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Class1
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Class2 and Class3 the same as Class1.

Read file:

```
    public FileClass DeSerialization()
    {
        FileClass data = new FileClass();

        BinaryFormatter binFormat = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (Stream fStream = new FileStream("test.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (GZipStream gzStream = new GZipStream(fStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                data = (FileClass)binFormat.Deserialize(gzStream);
                gzStream.Close();
            }

            fStream.Close();
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

I know how to create a new binary file in Python but I cannot transfer file structure from C#.

How will move a structure at Python and open file? If it's possible.

Comment: You'll probably have to start reading [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryformatter.cs#L217-L235), but realistically I'd use a different serializer (ProtoBuf or MessagePack, for example)

Comment: @John Thanks I necessarily study it. How I can understand I need cross-languages serializer. And I will not able just transfer structure. It will not work too. Do I right understand?

Comment: Pretty much. [Protocol Buffer Basics: C#](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial) says it quite well: _"Use .NET binary serialization with `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter` and associated classes. This ends up being very fragile in the face of changes, expensive in terms of data size in some cases. **It also doesn't work very well if you need to share data with applications written for other platforms.**"_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: @John Please tell me are ProtoBuf or MassagePack the best decision for my problem? What do you think? Let say I wrote app under Windows, now I need to rewrite on the cross-platform framework. And I choose Python (Qt) for that. Then I need cross-platform and cross-language serializer. Some correct C# app, it's no problem for me. I want to leave C# and use cross-platform for this app.

Comment: I've not used ProtoBuf before, but it's made by Google and it seems to be what a lot of people are using nowadays. MessagePack is an older product and I've only played with it, never used it in production.  I can't really tell you which one is best, so you'll probably have to evaluate them both (and any other options that exist).

Comment: @John Thanks a lot. Maybe you publish that decision as the post. I didn't think in this way. It suits me for now but I'll wait for other decisions for some days.